# How can I prevent my C++ program from crashing when a call to a library it must use is what causes it to crash?

Tags: c++, crash

Basically, my program uses code from a library whose source code I don't have access to. I know how to fix it but can't because I don't have the source code. The library terminates my process with exit code -1, after the library outputs "**FATAL ERROR**". I don't know much about C++, but I tried registering the six signals you can intercept with handlers and trying to rescue the program that way. I also tried a Try Catch block set up to catch every exception by using catch(...), neither worked.

Is there some way I can rescue my program? I basically want to tell it to do this:

1. run library code within my program

2a. if works, continue

2b. if crash, dont actually crash, wait a few seconds and go back to step 1

(Yes, I absolutely need to use this library)

Comment: maybe you should watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By7b19YIv8Q

Comment: what type of API is this ? Do you need to pass it pointers or just values ? Does it keep/share storage of data ? What does it return ? How often do you call it ? How long does a call take ? This will impact your answer significantly.

Comment: Not sure what kind. No. Not in this specific case. A status code representing whether it was successful or not, which is broken and the original devs never fixed it, if they fixed it in my case the problem wouldn't exist as I'd just get back "UNSUCESSFUL" code. Just once, a couple seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I you have a fatal error, sorry, your program *should* crash. This happens because either your library has bugs, or you're calling it incorrectly. In either case you're toast.

If you want to isolate this crash, make a separate helper process that makes the calls and if/when it tanks, you can just restart it and pick up where you left off.

Comment: Its definitely the former, because its supposed to return back a status code saying it failed, instead of crashing outright.

Currently I'm trying to make a guardian process that just reboots it if the standardoutput contains "**FATAL ERROR**"

Comment: You may need to employ a debugger here to find out what's going on and resolve this mystery.